# Create multiple source generator in one project

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

Can I create multiple **Incremental** source generators in one project or do I need to create separate projects for each generator separately?

An example of a project structure with source generators when:

```
Generators.csproj
  -- Generator1.cs
  -- Generator2.cs
```

Will this affect the productivity and speed of the build compared to the situation when the generators are located in different projects?

Comment: "SourceGenerator" or "**Incremental** SourceGenerator" ? Having done that for the latter, I can confidently tell you that, yes it is absolutely possible to have several different Generators in one Generator-Project. Cannot tell anything about the effect on build-speed but also: compared to what? Without generators? Compared to generators where each is in a separate project?